# How to customize the calendar web-part view in a sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint 2007 and I have a calendar web part in a sharepoint site for which I'd like to customize the view. To be more specific, when I choose the "Current Events" view, it lists the events with three columns: Title, Start Time, and End Time. My question is:

1- Is it possible to somehow customize these columns, for example to show only date and start time?

2- Is is possible to set the view to only show the events in the current month in the first page and when you navigate with Next and Previous buttons you move between months? 
More on this is that when I use Next button and then go back with Previous button the items in the list changes and it shows past items too.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.